# none of the following can be called with the arguments supplied ( ArrayAdapter )

Tags: kotlin, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

The problem I'm having is the arrayAdapter
how to solve the solution below
my goal is just to make auto Text Complete, which it is in the fragment

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O1pi5.png)

[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uEZWL.png)

hope I can overcome this and can make autoTextComplete and list view on the same fragment

Comment: Sharing the code in the question, and also sharing the exact error, what what the expected outcome instead of the error is very helpful for us to be able to provide solutions. Otherwise it will be very difficult for people to understand your needs.